# Variable via GET not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am carrying a variable via $_GET to a page which processes the action, the variable carries over correctly but the database won't update and throws an error.

Here is my link with a varible;

```html
echo "<td><a href='".plugins_url()."/myremovalsquote/inc/disable.php?id=".$active_partner->partner_id."' class='button-primary'>Disable</a></td>";
```

I then use the variable passed in my /disable.php

```html
$id = $_GET['id'];

echo $id;

global $wpdb;

if ($commit = $wpdb->query("UPDATE partners SET active='no' WHERE partner_id='"'$id'"'")) {
 echo 'Success';
} else {
 echo 'Failed';
}
```

The echo outputs the correct string, but then I get this error message.

```html
77
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/myremovalsquote/public_html/wp-content/plugins/myremovalsquote/inc/disable.php on line 9
```

Comment: It looks like $wpdb is not returning anything - you should var_dump() it to have a look - my guess would be that you need to require_once('wp-load.php') with the correct path to that file (its in the root of the site) in your disable.php file to make sure WordPress functions are enabled.

Comment: @SimonPollard `$wpdb` is only available if you have loaded WordPress, but `disable.php` is just a PHP file that is not loading WordPress.

Comment: @doublesharp indeed - hopefully he will look at your answer then - I was unaware of AJAX listener functions which looks like an elegant solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a PHP file directly without loading WordPress, so `$wpdb` and it's method aren't available to you.

You can fix this by including `wp-load.php`, however this is generally considered to be bad form, as explained in [*Don't include wp-load please*](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/).

A better solution would be to create an [AJAX listener](http://justinsilver.com/technology/wordpress/creating-ajax-functions-in-wordpress/), and then call that from your link (it doesn't really have to be a JavaScript request or JSON response). You would need to pass in your `action` to call the right PHP method, along with your other variables.

```
// attach action "handler_33762965" to the handler_33762965() function for admin (wp_ajax_*) and front end (wp_ajax_nopriv_*)
add_action( 'wp_ajax_handler_33762965', 'handler_33762965' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_norpriv_handler_33762965', 'handler_33762965' );
function handler_33762965(){
    // make sure the ID is set before grabbing it
    $id = isset( $_GET['id'] )? $_GET['id'] : 0;
    // do stuff
    exit();
}
```

Your link would look like the following.

```php
<a href="/wp-load.php?action=handler_33762965&id=<?php echo $id; ?>">link</a>
```